# LG V60 Keyboard changed overnight

Tags: keyboard, lg

Up until the last couple of days my keyboard had a certain layout with long-press options for the letters and also a row of buttons for emojis, gifs and other fun option at the top.  Now, it's just the keyboard and it seems like that part is less functional with the long press options.  How can I get it back to the original keyboard version?  Is the row of emoji and gif buttons part of the keyboard or is that some other feature I'm not thinking of?

Additional information: I like to listen to YouTube videos when I work out, but this occasionally results in icons being dragged around or menus getting opened by my pockets. This could be a pocket-dialing scenario or something where I was glomped by my dog while trying to do something and fat fingered some commands by accident.

Comment: Which keyboard app do you use? You can check in Android settings which keyboard is configured to be used. One common keyboard is GBoard which is used on many Android phones by default but I don't remember if LG had an own keyboard app.

Comment: Based on my experience, Gboard has all the features you mentioned. Probably you accidentally pressed the change language/keyboard (globe) icon or long-pressed the spacebar and now it's changed to another keyboard.

Comment: @Robert LG Keyboard is the keyboard app.  I haven't been able to find it in the apps section of settings though.  Seems buried in some hidden category or something.